# Finding the whether vectors are linearly independent or dependent

Tags: vectors, proof-explanation

> Example: Let $a$, $b$, and $c$ be a system of non-zero, non-coplanar
> vectors. Examine whether the vectors: $$f=5a+6b+7c$$
>
> $$g=7a-8b+9c$$
>
> $$h=3a+20b+5c$$ are linearly independent or dependent.

and the answer goes as follows:

> Suppose $f$, $g$, and $h$ are linearly independent.
>
> Then, $αf+βg+γh=0$ where $α=0, β=0, γ=0$
>
> Consider $αf+βg+γh=0$ -(1), substituting $f$, $g$, and $h$ into (1)
> and noting that $a$, $b$, and $c$ are non-coplanar vectors, we get:
>
> $$5α+7β+3γ=0 -eq(2)$$ $$6α-8β+20γ=0 -eq(3)$$ $$7α+9β+5γ=0 -eq(4)$$
>
> (2) - (4) $$α+β+γ=0 -eq(5)$$
>
> (3) & (4) substitution gives $α=-2γ$ and $β=γ$.
>
> Hence there exists non-zero scalars such that (1) holds. This
> contradicts (1) hence the given vectors are linearly dependent.

My question is, how does the $α=-2γ$ and $β=γ$ show that they are non-zero?

Comment: $\gamma$ was left arbitrary, so you could substitute any nonzero vector in for it.

Comment: Because $(-2\gamma) f+\gamma g+\gamma h=0$ holds for *any* $\gamma$, so you can choose any $\gamma \ne 0$. In fact, you can "see" that $f = \frac{1}{2}(g+h)$, which is what the solution says.

Comment: The quoted answer is very poorly written.

Comment: @Karl It's from my textbook, it's very difficult to decipher these examples.

Comment: Another was would be to notice that the matrix [ 5 6 7 ; 7 -8 9 ; 2 20 5 ] has determinant zero, hence the range space has dimension $\le 2$.

Comment: To show that the vectors are not linearly independent, just note that $g+h-2f=0$. The quoted answer shows some steps to find such a linear combination (take $\gamma=1$ at the end), but some of the logical language is wrong.

Comment: As a side note, you can also solve this problem by setting up the coefficients of $f,g,h$ in a $3\times 3$ matrix and computing the determinant. If the determinant is $0$, which it is, then your system is linearly independent. As for why this works, it has to do with matrix multiplication and invertibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a fixed version of the answer.

By definition, $f,g,h$ are linearly independent iff the equation $\alpha f+\beta g+\gamma h=0$ has $\alpha=0,\beta=0,\gamma=0$ as its only solution. So let's assume $\alpha f+\beta g+\gamma h=0$, try to solve for $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$, and see if there are nonzero solutions. We have

$$\alpha(5a+6b+7c)+\beta(7a-8b+9c)+\gamma(3a+20b+5c)=0$$

which rearranges to

$$(5\alpha+7\beta+3\gamma)a+(6\alpha−8\beta+20\gamma)b+(7\alpha+9\beta+5\gamma)c=0.$$

Now use the fact that $a,b,c$ are linearly independent vectors (this is what is meant by "non-coplanar"). This allows us to conclude from the vector equation above that the three scalar coefficients in parentheses are all $0$. So we have the system of linear equations

$$
5α+7β+3γ=0\\
6α−8β+20γ=0\\
7α+9β+5γ=0.
$$

By [Gaussian elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination) (or just ad-hoc application of [elementary row operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_matrix#Elementary_row_operations)), we find that the above system is *equivalent* to the system

$$
1α+0β+2γ=0\\
0α+1β-1γ=0\\
0α+0β+0γ=0
$$

or just

$$
\alpha=-2\gamma\\
\beta=\gamma.
$$

Since our system with three unknowns reduces to just two equations, there will be nonzero solutions. We can choose any desired value for $\gamma$ and get corresponding values of $\alpha,\beta$ to form a solution. For example, taking $\gamma=1$, we get $\alpha=-2,\beta=1$. And indeed we can verify that

$$(-2)f+1g+1h=0$$

which shows directly that $f,g,h$ are not linearly independent.