# Linearly independent or dependent - how to show?

Tags: vectors

Let $a$, $b$ and $c$ be a system of non-zero, non-coplanar vectors. Find a relation between the vectors $f$, $g$, $h$, $j$ given by:

$$f=a+3b+4c$$

$$g=a-2b+3c$$

$$h=a+5b-2c$$

$$j=6a+14b+4c$$

How can we show this?

My attempt:

Let's assume that they are linearly independent.

$$αf+βg+γh+λj=0 -eq(1)$$

Where each of the scalars is equal to zero $α = β = γ = λ =0$.

Substituting $f$, $g$, $h$, $j$ into (1) we get:

$$α + β + γ + 6λ=0$$
$$3α -2β + 5γ + 14λ=0$$
$$4α + 3β - 2γ + 4λ=0$$

Using this result, how do I prove that at least one of these scalars is zero or at least one of them is non-zero?

Here is an example way the textbook solves this:
[Finding the whether vectors are linearly independent or dependent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4714046/finding-the-whether-vectors-are-linearly-independent-or-dependent)

Comment: you end with a 3 by 4 system; write its matrix of coefficients and row reduce that.

Comment: You can't create 4 li vectors from linear combinations of 3 vectors.

Comment: You are looking for non zero $(\alpha,..., \lambda)$ such that $\alpha f + \cdots + \lambda  j = 0$.

Comment: @copper.hat Apologies, but can you elaborate on that a little?

Comment: The last set of equations above have 3 equations in 4 variables. By following @WillJagy's suggestion, you can show that 3 of the variables are a function of a fourth. This will give a linear relationship between the vectors $f,...,j$.

Comment: $f+2g+3h=j~~~~$